# cloud firestore security rules - get a parent doc in list request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

im trying to check a parent document data when a user list a subcollection.
Here my rules:

```
match /configs/{config}{
  //everybody can list the configs
  allow read: if isAuthenticated()
  match /sources/{source} {
    allow list:
      if isAuthenticated() && 
      canViewProduct(
        request.auth.token.email,database,
        get(/configs/$(config)).data.projectName,'filetransfer')
  }
```

But, when I'm trying a list of the /sources like below, there is the error:

```
app.collection("configs").doc("flow01").collection.("sources").get()

    FirebaseError: 
false for 'list' @ L117, Service call error. Function: [get], Argument: [path_value {
  segments {
    simple: "configs"
  }
  segments {
    simple: "flow01"
  }
}
]. for 'list' @ L131
```

i dont understand why the "get(/configs/$(config))" is failing, because the parent doc "flow01" exist...

Can't i use a **get() function** in **list** operation ?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `get()`, you have to provide a full path to a document.  What you have now is very much incomplete - you can't use any sort of relative paths.  A full `get()` would look more like this:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/configs/$(config))
```

I suggest also reading the documentation for [accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in security rules.

Comment: OMG thanks you Doug so much... That was just in front of my eyes...